# Allocate memory dynamically to eclipse

Tags: eclipse, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

In `eclipse.ini`, there is an argument that we can set to allocate memory dynamically to Eclipse. Does someone know what argument is it?

Comment: I've read somewhere that other than xms and xmx, there is another argument that can be added to make dynamic memory allocation

Comment: Can you describe more about the 'dynamically' allocating memory?

Comment: i.e. Eclipse can take any amount of memory depending on the how much it needs

Answer (score 1):

You can't tell Eclipse to take as much memory as it needs. It's a JVM, so you have to tell it the maximum amount of memory up front. (see, for example [What does Java option -Xmx stand for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374455/what-does-java-option-xmx-stand-for))

You can allocate more memory using the -Xmx and -Xms memory options in the eclipse.ini.
This is mine. Note the three lines at the end which set the memory options:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.2.R36x_v20101222
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-clean
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms256m
-Xmx1280m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

Comment: in case i set Xmx a high value, does it becomes a problem?

Comment: Yes it can become a problem if you set it too high. It allocates that much memory for your eclipse.