# Increase heap size in java for weka

Tags: java, memory, jvm, weka

I'm trying to increase the heap size in java for weka which keeps crashing.  I used the suggested line:

```
> java -Xmx500m -classpath
```

but I get the following error:

```
-classpath requires class path specification
```

I'm not sure what this means.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What I found was the actual issue was in the file `'RunWeka.ini'` in `'\Program Files (x86)\Weka-3-6'`.  I opened it with notepad and in the middle of the file there is a line `'maxheap = 512m'`.

I changed the line to read `'maxheap=2000m'`, saved the file and reloaded weka and this fixed my problems.

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it or not but it worked for me.

Comment: well you change the max heap size from the the command line as well while running weka.jar. Its the same thing

Comment: More recent versions of Weka accept the option `-m`. So you can just run `weka -m 2g`.

Comment: For version 3.8 I added maxheap=5000m, I cant see the change in Help >> SystemInfo memory.max . If changed at this level its not reflecting either.

Answer (score 13):

Run this command in your terminal:

```
java -Xmx1024m -jar weka.jar
```

Answer (score 12):

Omit the `-classpath` option. Use just `-Xmx500m` option.

So, instead of just:

```
java weka.core.Instances data/soybean.arff
```

you do:

```
java -Xmx500m weka.core.Instances data/soybean.arff
```

If you run weka via some script (RunWeka.bat for example), then you need to modify that script (with some text editor like notepad).

Answer (score 9):

If you're using Weka 3.8.1 on Windows you can save yourself a lot of trouble by editing the `javaOpts` parameter. The parameter `maxheap` isn't used anymore, so you can set `javaOpts` like this in **RunWeka.ini** file:

```
javaOpts= -Xmx1040m
```

Where `1040m` is the amount of memory you want to allocate.

Mind that the file is case sensitive.

There are a lot of ways to set this up, but this is the faster way to get Weka runing on a Windows environment at this version.

Edit: If you want Weka to use more than `1gb` on windows, you need to have JDK installed. Regular JRE wont do it.

Answer (score 5):

The **official Weka answer** (for all operating systems and Weka versions) can be found on http://weka.wikispaces.com/OutOfMemoryException.

In case you are using a recent Weka version on Windows, [the answer](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Java+Virtual+Machine#Invocation) is:

> Modify the `maxheap` parameter in the `RunWeka.ini` file.

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu i had the same problem 
but i solve it by increasing the amount of memory to use for the Java Virtual Machine
 run this : weka -m 1024m

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify a classpath after `-classpath`, similar to the `PATH` env variable you need to specify the path where Java can find the classes.

The `-Xmx500m` setting looks fine, except that I would suggest to use 512m.

Comment: something like: java -Xmx512m -c:\Program Files(x86)\Java ?

Comment: you do not need to set a classpath for the Java libs, only to your own classes, so it could be `java -Xmx512m -classpath .` if your compiled classes are in the working directory. Or you compile them into a jar file, then you do java `-Xmx512m -classpath c:\path\to\your\jarfile.jar'

Answer (score 3):

For Mac OS, you have to edit a configuration file in order to increase the heap size of the Weka UI application.

I am repeating what I wrote in: [Is there a workaround to solve "Java heap space" memory error when the max heap value has been already specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078584/is-there-a-workaround-to-solve-java-heap-space-memory-error-when-the-max-heap)

1. Quit out of Weka if it is running.
2. cd into /Applications/weka-XXX.app/Contents , or wherever your weka executable was installed. There will be a file called `Info.plist` there. It is an XML text file. I suggest you save a copy of it to another location, as you'll need to edit it in the next step.
3. Open the `Info.plist` (XML) file in your favorite text editor and look for a block that says "VMOptions". There should be a value that says "-Xmx256M" or something similar that [specifies the maximum heap size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374455/what-does-java-option-xmx-stand-for). You should change that value to something bigger, such as "-Xmx1024M".
4. Start Weka.

Answer (score 1):

I am running Weka 3.6 in windows. This is what i did.
Go to the Weka installation directory and you will find a RunWeka.bat file. Open this file in a text editor and add -Xmx argument in the java command line.

for instance this sets to 4GB memory,
%_java% -Xmx4096m -classpath . RunWeka -i .\RunWeka.ini -w .\weka.jar -c %_cmd% "%2"

Answer (score 1):

The official Weka answer is right..But....crucial is to first get rid of all JVM files and install the relevant 32 or 64 bit Java version. Not using the relevant version causes many problems including the impossibility to increase the heap further than 1024m (by changing the ini file).

Answer (score 1):

Weka 3.9.2 also does not has the option of maxheap anymore. RunWeka.ini have the option of javaOpts, So you may change the below to your required memory allocation,

```
javaOpts=%JAVA_OPTS%   ---- > javaOpts= -Xmx1024m
```

Here 1024m is the customised amount of memory you want to allocate.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it using this command

```
    java -Xmx1024m -[weka classifier] -t [training file path]
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers above are too old (last one is 1 year ago).
I had same issue with my **WEKA (version 3.8.1)** on Windows 10.

I had a problem to update the heap size , the way I fixed it is by adding an environment variable (under control panel) as follows:

```
JAVA_OPTS = -Xms30000m -Xmx30000m
```

**Tip**: Just ensure that RunWeka.ini is using this environment variable.

In the above example I give WEKA 30GB. It works.

*Hope it will be helpful for some people.*

Answer (score 0):

You should also see if default thread stack size 20MB is enough. Increase the value to 50MB in the file /Applications/weka-3-8-1-oracle-jvm.app/Contents/Info.plist (on MAC) like below:

```
<string>-Xss50M</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

> If we are using Weka Workbench CLI or Knowledge explorer we need to
>   change as below.

As the documentation suggests the runtime parameter should be -Xmx[size_required]m where [size_required] is memory size you intend to keep to avoid memory exception.

Open RunWeka.ini

> Define maxheap=[size_required]G

In my case I kept maxheap=4G , One can set like maxheap=4096m and **add -Xmx#maxheap# to all the run options at # setups** (prefixed with "cmd_") sections next to java commands
like below

```
cmd_default=javaw -Xmx#maxheap# ...............
cmd_console=cmd.exe /K start cmd.exe ..................
cmd_explorer=java -Xmx#maxheap# .................
cmd_knowledgeFlow=java -Xmx#maxheap#....................

maxheap=4G
```

Verify the same by restarting Weka and Help>>SystemInfo

Answer (score 0):

If you run weka from the command line but not through java i.e. typing `weka` into the command line, instead of typing

```
weka
```

specify the memory flag

```
weka -m 1024m
```

This will specify 1024 megabytes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running weka via weka.sh, you can directly run it with memory option.
For example,

```
sh weka.sh -memory 10g
```

This will increase the heap size to 10Gb (tested using Weka 3.8.4 on Ubuntu 18.04)