# Changing the Heap Size in Weka

Tags: java, weka

I've seen many resources telling me what line to add, but I can't find any resources that give step by step instructions on what to do to increase the memory size.

Thanks

[Can somebody explain this in greater detail, where does this line go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662781/increase-heap-size-in-java-for-weka)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://weka.wikispaces.com/Java+Virtual+Machine

I'm pretty sure you just increase the JVM size no setting in Weka specifically.

These links may help too:
http://weka.wikispaces.com/OutOfMemoryException
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

Depending on your OS it may be different how you go about changing those settings, but the gist is to raise the values of `-vmargs -Xms256M -Xmx512M`

**EDIT**

This is basic instructions for Windows XP, but I'm sure the same applies for Windows 7 or you can easily figure it out:

http://www.duckware.com/pmvr/howtoincreaseappletmemory.html

Synopsis:

Start --> Control Panel --> Open 'Java Plug-in' --> Java Tab --> View 'Java Applet Runtime Settings' --> Change/Add option to the Java Runtime Parameter

Something like:

`-vmargs -Xms256M -Xmx512M` or even `-Xmx512M` alone should work.

Comment: Sorry, where do I change the java -Xmx512m.

The weka wiki page doesn't seem to have any instructions for that. It just says "With the Sun JVM you can do this via the -Xmx option".

Comment: Which Operating System are you using? Which version of the JVM/JDK do you have installed?

Comment: Windows 7 64 bit.  JRE 6 JDK 1.6 . Is that all that's needed? Thanks by the way.

Comment: Updated my answer with instructions...should help.

Answer (score 5):

Depends solely on how you start it, but assuming you're using the bat that's included: Just edit `RunWeka.ini` and change the `maxheap=something` variable (should exist but if not create it) to whatever you like.

e.g.: `maxheap=4g` sets the heap to 4gb.

Comment: Thanks. Also it's not letting me save edits. I made sure to close all instances of Weka but it's still not letting me. Any ideas?

Comment: I didn't know that it was a rights problem, but that worked, thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

This is better step by step to increase Java memory for windows 7 with sanpshots

Regards

http://www.wikihow.com/Increase-Java-Memory-in-Windows-7

Answer (score 0):

The answers above are too old (last one is 1 year ago).
I had same issue with my **WEKA (version 3.8.1)** on Windows 10.

I had a problem to update the heap size , the way I fixed it is by adding an environment variable (under control panel) as follows:

```
JAVA_OPTS = -Xms30000m -Xmx30000m
```

**Tip**: Just ensure that RunWeka.ini is using this environment variable.

In the above example I give WEKA 30GB. It works.

*Hope it will be helpful for some people.*