# Out of Memory Error in Weka despite Changing Heap Size

Tags: heap-memory, weka

I'm trying to load a data set of 35K records. It gave the out of memory error:

======================================================================

Not enough memory (less than 50MB left on heap) Please loada smaller data set or use a larger heap size.

intial size : 0MB

current memory (heap used): 13.6MB

max. memory (heap) avaliable: 63.6MB

======================================================================

I tried following the solutions offered by increasing heap size (from 1024M, I changed it to 2000M like what [this solution offered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662781/increase-heap-size-in-java-for-weka?rq=1)) but still I get the same error when I reload the data. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Windows or on Linux / Mac?

On Windows, you can set an environment variable JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1500m

You can do this on the command line, but then you must start weka from within that command line.

To change windows permanently, not only for this command window:

This page contains short instructions/walkthroughs for the different versions of windows:
https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

In these instructions, instead of changing/adding the PATH environment-variable, add/change the JAVA_OPTS environment-variable with a high value. Again, do *not* change PATH, change JAVA_OPTS. Or create it.