# How to increase the heap size in WEKA?

Tags: out-of-memory, weka, heap-size

I am learning WEKA, I want to increase the heap size.

I did Q&A researches, most of the answers showed that heap size can be changed in **RunWeka.ini**, but I couldn't find **RunWeka.ini** and also maxheap.

**My WEKA version is Weka 3.8.4**
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increase heap size in java for weka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662781/increase-heap-size-in-java-for-weka)

Comment: @xuan Did the solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. You have two options.

**Option 1:**

1. Open the notepad or text editor.
2. Write the following statement inside.

   ```
   java -Xmx8000m -cp "weka.jar" weka.gui.GUIChooser
   ```

   Here "-Xmx" sets the maximum memory that Weka can use. Another
   version of this parameter is "-Xms". This parameter sets the minimum
   memory that Weka will use. "8000m" means 8000 MB. You can also write
   "4g" and specify in Gigabytes.
3. Save the file in the notebook as shown in the picture below. For
   example "run.bat"

[image]

4. Copy the file and paste it into the directory where Weka is located.
5. I think it will be useful when you double-click the file you pasted.

*Note:* If you are using 32 bit java, you cannot increase more than
8GB. No problem on 64 bit.

**Option 2:**

1. Enter the folder where Weka is located.
2. Open the RunWeka.ini file. Find the line shown in the code below
   and enter the value you want as shown.

   javaOpts=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xmx8048m
3. Save and run Weka.

I saw this option on the site ([link here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_increase_the_heap_size_in_WEKA)). But I don't know if it works. I think it works.

I am using the first option and it works. Good luck.