# How to increse heap size in weka 3-8-6

Tags: java, weka

I face issues when I want to do the "cluster function"
in weka. When I click the start button, it shows like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTmWq.png)

I searched on google the solutions, mostly is outdated due to old version or I didn't unerstand it, how I can increase it

Note: I installed last version of weka

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Instead, please post them [using a code block](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). Instead, please use code blocks for that. Aside from that, did you try increasing the maximum heap space using `-Xmx`?

Comment: I tried, but I didn't know what the correct to place Xmx, should I put it in CL or in weka.ini?

Comment: Is there any place for jvm arguments/VM args or something similar? Do you execute a `java` command anywhere? Normally, it's `java -Xmx2G <other parts of command>` or similar. Alternatively, you could try adding it (e.g. `-Xmx2G` for a heap size of 2GB) to the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable

Comment: Also see [Increase heap size in java for weka](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8662781) - Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `_JAVA_OPTIONS` environment variable as per [OutOfMemoryException](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/faqs/OutOfMemoryException/) FAQ on the [Weka wiki](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/).

For setting environment variables on Windows, please see here:

- [Windows 10](https://www.alphr.com/environment-variables-windows-10/)
- [Windows 11](https://www.alphr.com/set-environment-variables-windows-11/)