# maximum jvm memory that I can allocate

Tags: java

I am using 512 mb ram. I know we can increase the jvm heap memory by passing two arguments..

What is the maximum value that I can give for `-Xmx` argument for 512 mb ram to work system smoothly.

Comment: This question may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374455/what-does-java-option-xmx-stand-for

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what else you're running. If you run out of available RAM, the operating system will swap to disk. If you overcommit your RAM a little bit, the stuff that gets swapped to disk probably is the unused stuff and it doesn't hurt too much.

If you overcommit your RAM too much, the system will churn on the hard drive and everything slows down unbearably. There is no way for someone on the internet to guess at what this precise point may be on your computer, so you'll just have to try various values of the `-Xmx` argument to find out where the breaking point is.

Comment: Seriously though... 512MB. I'm guessing you're on a corporate network with no freedom to spec or buy your own hardware, but that was a nice amount of RAM to have twelve years ago. There's a good business case to be made for your boss to spend $15 on an upgrade to 4GB. You'll earn that amount of money in productivity within the week, possibly the day.