# How to set the -Xmx when start running a jar file?

Tags: java, jar

As we know that we can set `-Xmx1024M` in `window->preferences->java->installed jres->edit->default vm arguments` in **eclipse**. But when I package this project into a runnable jar file, how can I set the `-Xmx1024M` when running the jar via `java -jar A.jar`?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: java -jar -Xmx1024M A.jar

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try `java -Xmx1024m` filename.

I found this on StackOverflow [What does Java option -Xmx stand for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374455/what-does-java-option-xmx-stand-for) and use it when I start Netbeans for instance.

use it like this

```
java -Xmx1024m -jar JavaApplication.jar
```

info:
`-Xmxn`
Specify the maximum size, in bytes, of the memory allocation pool. This value must be a multiple of 1024 greater than 2MB. Append the letter k or K to indicate kilobytes, or m or M to indicate megabytes. The default value is 64MB. The upper limit for this value will be approximately 4000m on Solaris 7 and Solaris 8 SPARC platforms and 2000m on Solaris 2.6 and x86 platforms, minus overhead amounts.

Comment: Please note that in your proposed solution `-Xmx1024m` is passed to the executed jar file, not to the JVM as intended. See my answer for details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42207984/7492402

Comment: The answer above is wrong - all JVM arguments should be passed right after java: i.e. java -Xmx4G -Xms1G .... your_jar.jar

Comment: ABOVE IS WRONG SEE ANSWER BELOW by @PhilippMerkle

Comment: Man I do not get how google's algorithm works, but that fetched answer made me waste so much time

Answer (score 173):

Unfortunately, existing answers are wrong in one crucial point.

**`-Xmx` must be passed to the Java runtime environment, not to the executed jar.**

Wrong:

```
java -jar JavaApplication.jar -Xmx1024m
```

Correct:

```
java -Xmx1024m -jar JavaApplication.jar
```

More specifically, the [java launcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) needs to be used as follows:

> java [options] -jar file.jar [arguments]

- `[options]` are passed to the Java runtime environment
- `[arguments]` are passed to the main function

The `-Xmx` parameter belongs to the (nonstandard) JVM options, and--being an option--needs to be listed before -jar (or at least before file.jar). The JVM will not recognize an `-Xmx` argument passed to the main function as proposed in other answers.

Comment: A pitfall for the unwary - not to be funny, but the `-Xmx` parameter syntax is case sensitive. I was beating my head against the wall trying to figure out why I couldn't get this to work by modifying shortcut target properties, and that was why.

Comment: I had tried both ways, and used jvsualvm to see the jvm args, it shows JVM arguments as -Xmx2048m in both cases. Any clue as to why this happens?

Answer (score 10):

Three methods:

- Command Line:
- Instruct your users to run your application using "java -Xmx1024m -jar SampleJavaApp.jar"
- Java Control Panel:
- Instruct your users to dedicate more memory to java by default: [Win7 guide](http://www.wikihow.com/Increase-Java-Memory-in-Windows-7)
- Restart your jar with the appropriate Xmx value.

The last option is "evil" but doesn't require any extra effort from your users.  Here's a sample block of code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    String currentPath=SampleJavaApp.class
          .getProtectionDomain()
          .getCodeSource().getLocation()
          .toURI().getPath()
          .replace('/', File.separator.charAt(0)).substring(1);
    if(args.length==0 && Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/1024/1024<980) {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -Xmx1024m -jar "+currentPath+" restart");
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Best solution! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Correct way to set Xmx value for jar file at run time is:

```
java -Xmx512m -jar Application.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

user1361991 > I like your evil option but I cannot comment it since I am still a newbie here. Anyway, I thought it deserved a little enhancement since I find it lacks the stderr and stdout redirection.

```
String currentPath= MyClass.class
    .getProtectionDomain()
    .getCodeSource().getLocation()
    .toURI().getPath()
    .replace('/', File.separatorChar).substring(1) ;
if ( args.length == 0 && Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()<512*1024*1024) {
    Process p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar -Xmx512M " + currentPath + " restart") ;
    new StreamGobbler(p.getInputStream()).start() ;
    new StreamGobbler(p.getErrorStream()).start() ;
    p.waitFor() ;
    return ;
}
```

and the StreamGobbler source (probably retrieved from somewhere on the Internet to be honest and modified a little, I can't remember):

```
public class StreamGobbler
    extends Thread
{
    public StreamGobbler( InputStream is )
    {
        this(is, System.out) ;
    }

    public StreamGobbler( InputStream is, PrintStream ps )
    {
        this.is= is ;
        this.ps= ps ;
    }
    private final InputStream is ;
    private final PrintStream ps ;

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try {
            InputStreamReader isr= new InputStreamReader(is) ;
            BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(isr) ;
            for ( String line ; (line= br.readLine()) != null ; ) {
                ps.println(line) ;
            }
       }
       catch ( IOException ioe ) {
           ioe.printStackTrace() ;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "stderr and stdout redirection"? 
and what does stream gobbler do?

Comment: Hello and sorry for the late answer. The "problem" I wanted to address with the original evil solution was that it was hiding the output of the program when it's originally launched from the terminal (you can't see a simple log or the stacktrace if there is a non caught exception for example). So I modified it to redirect the output from System.out and System.err from the relaunched JVM to the original one. The little drawback is that the original program has to wait for the second to end, so the first one won't release the RAM immediately.