# Specify JVM parameters whilst creating an executable jar (not when executing the jar)

Tags: java, jar

I am ***building***  (not executing !)  an executable jar that has 81K clases in it.  Building a jar file that big is gradually slowing down during the building process until a `java.lang.OutofMemoryException` is thrown.

So - then how to specify the `-Xmx1024m` to give the jvm used while building the jar  some extra memory headroom?

Note the

> jar

command does not accept any `-D` command line parameters.

Now I did try setting

```
export JVM_OPTS=-Xmx1024m
```

and it *may* have helped - since the jar command did work. But I have no clear way to know if it did in fact get applied.

Comment: Can you tell us exactly how you are running the JAR?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set the -Xmx when start running a jar file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149304/how-to-set-the-xmx-when-start-running-a-jar-file)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen   No - that is for *running* a jar file. i am *building* a jar file here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `JVM_OPTS` **does** resolve this issue

```
export JVM_OPTS="-Xmx2048m"
jar -cvfm myjar.jar /tmp/manifest.txt classdir/
```

The other answers -as well as the vote to close - jumped to conclusions that this OP were about *executing* the jar file via `java -jar myjar.jar`.

The problem was - as stated in OP - that there are tens of thousands of classes to include - and it was overwhelming the default JVM settings - leading to OOME. I could watch the `jar` command slow down towards the end before it just gave up. After adding the JVM_OPTS there were no more issues in **building** the jar.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the point. It's clear now and I'll delete my comments.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of memory must be determined *by process*, at the time of starting the JVM:

```
java -Xmx1024m ... -jar my.jar ...
```

See:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionX.html

Comment: That is for *running* a jar file. I am *creating* a jar file here.

Comment: AFAIK the memory settings are determined at the time when the JVM starts, and they are _not_ stored within your JAR file.

Comment: Yes, I mean that: You cannot specify execution parameters at the time of _creating_ a jar (read Serge Ballesta's answer).

Comment: @LittleSanti  Actually one can - I have an answer on it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

The build phase is different from the run phase. At build time, you compile java sources, and assemble them along with some resources in a jar. No JVM options are involved here.

Then at run time, you can pass options to the JVM through the `java` command. You cannot include JVM options at build time, because :

- you cannot know on which JVM the jar will be executed not on what system
- you cannot know if special options (notably -X ones) will be accepted on the JVM
- you cannot know the available resources

For those reasons, it would make little sense if any to specify run time options at build time, that's the reason why it is not possible.

Comment: This answer is not addressing the OP: it is *not* referring to `java -jar`. The OP is about *creating* the jar file in the first place.  Why are you referring to "target" jvm's?  I only need the jvm *creating* the jar.