# How to increase jvm memory

Tags: java

I want to alter (increase) java memory limit (JRE on windows pc).
I fount following commands everywhere:

-Xms     set initial Java heap size

-Xmx     set maximum Java heap size

for example -Xmx1024m.

But my Question is where! do I have to enter this command. Sorry for this beginner question. Normally I do not have any contact to java.

Comment: those are parameters that you pass in the command  line when you start the app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the -Xmx when start running a jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149304/how-to-set-the-xmx-when-start-running-a-jar-file)

Comment: make sure to read this answer aswell ;-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149304/how-to-set-the-xmx-when-start-running-a-jar-file/42207984#42207984

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using eclipse and try to run standalone java then use vm argument section in run configuration tab .For tomcat or app server in setenv script file put

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=384m
```

for executable jar

```
java -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -jar FILENAME.jar
```

Comment: I dont use eclipe. I have a complete java application on a server in my network which I execute with a double-click on the .jar file

Answer (score 0):

Those are Arguments for the ***Virtual Machine*** that you pass in the command line when you start the app

example:

in the console doing:

> java -Xms256m -Xmx1024m  HelloWorld

or if you are in eclipse (or any other ide)
[image]