# AnyLogic throws error upon start

Tags: java, anylogic

When trying to start AnyLogic, it throws the following error:

> Failed to create Java Virtual Machine

Comment: AnyLogic isn't a programming tool, it's a simulation tool. Off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these steps in order:

1. Try to restart your machine.
2. If that does not help, go into the AnyLogic installation folder (somewhere like C:/Program Files/AnyLogic 7 Professional/) and open the file AnyLogic.ini with an editor.
3. Replace the existing line "-Xmx1024M" with "-Xmx256M"
4. save & close.

Comment: That's going to vary based on your machine. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5374501/3280538

Comment: good point, thx. So to solve the problem, you will want to *change* the existing value, most likely to a lower value.

Comment: Only if your issue is heap allocation. There could be a number of reasons why the JVM fails to load.