# Why did the OOM-killer close java if top logs only showed 8% memory usage at the time?

Tags: java, linux, kernel

I have a script that monitors the output of top and here is what the system looked like before java invoked the oom-killer:

```
TopLogger time: 2016-03-23:07:45:07.691254496
top - 07:45:07 up 1 day, 14:58,  2 users,  load average: 1.60, 1.59, 1.61
Tasks: 179 total,   9 running, 170 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  8.4 us,  7.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 83.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.3 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   2038540 total,  1283840 used,   754700 free,     7372 buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.   332372 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 2336 root       0 -20  397256 162572  12568 S 131.0  8.0   2674:22 java
28845 odroid    20   0    4860   1056    728 R  31.4  0.1   0:00.10 top
 1047 root      20   0  123136  22964  14236 S  10.5  1.1 113:30.21 Xorg
 1181 root      20   0   12616    772    604 S   5.2  0.0  65:49.23 eGTouchD
21660 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   5.2  0.0   0:09.14 kworker/7:2
    1 root      20   0   24052   3200   1808 S   0.0  0.2   0:28.11 systemd
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.44 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   3:40.20 ksoftirqd/0
```

As you can see java was consuming using 8% of the memory. The system itself had over 754 MB of memory available. At the same time, the kernel logs show that somehow this caused java to trigger the oom-killer:

```
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.599648] [c1] java invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x40d0, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.599842] [c1] CPU: 1 PID: 3499 Comm: java Not tainted 3.10.96-78 #1
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.599858] [c1] Backtrace:
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.599897] [c1] [<c0012da4>] (dump_backtrace+0x0/0x114) from [<c0013014>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.599912] [c1]  r7:000040d0 r6:da80d600 r5:00000000 r4:da906000
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.599960] [c1] [<c0012ff4>] (show_stack+0x0/0x24) from [<c062aff8>] (dump_stack+0x24/0x28)
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.599983] [c1] [<c062afd4>] (dump_stack+0x0/0x28) from [<c062a520>] (dump_header+0x8c/0x244)
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600009] [c1] [<c062a494>] (dump_header+0x0/0x244) from [<c00ed684>] (oom_kill_process+0x364/0x3dc)
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600033] [c1] [<c00ed320>] (oom_kill_process+0x0/0x3dc) from [<c00edc20>] (out_of_memory+0x33c/0x390)
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600059] [c1] [<c00ed8e4>] (out_of_memory+0x0/0x390) from [<c00f241c>] (__alloc_pages_nodemask+0xb0c/0xb20)
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600083] [c1] [<c00f1910>] (__alloc_pages_nodemask+0x0/0xb20) from [<c00f2450>] (__get_free_pages+0x20/0x3c)
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600110] [c1] [<c00f2430>] (__get_free_pages+0x0/0x3c) from [<c04e7858>] (snd_malloc_pages+0x44/0x9c)
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600138] [c1] [<c04e7814>] (snd_malloc_pages+0x0/0x9c) from [<c04dcf90>] (snd_pcm_attach_substream+0x210/0x394)
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600154] [c1]  r5:00000000 r4:dd90a600
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600193] [c1] [<c04dcd80>] (snd_pcm_attach_substream+0x0/0x394) from [<c04e2590>] (snd_pcm_open_substream+0x24/0xc4)
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600220] [c1] [<c04e256c>] (snd_pcm_open_substream+0x0/0xc4) from [<c04e26e8>] (snd_pcm_open+0xb8/0x208)
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600234] [c1]  r5:dc68e000 r4:dd90a400
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600270] [c1] [<c04e2630>] (snd_pcm_open+0x0/0x208) from [<c04e28f0>] (snd_pcm_playback_open+0x4c/0x6c)
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600302] [c1] [<c04e28a4>] (snd_pcm_playback_open+0x0/0x6c) from [<c04d1dcc>] (snd_open+0xa8/0x1d4)
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600315] [c1]  r5:dc68e000 r4:00000010
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600351] [c1] [<c04d1d24>] (snd_open+0x0/0x1d4) from [<c01396ac>] (chrdev_open+0x98/0x178)
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600367] [c1]  r9:00000000 r8:da907e98 r7:de3a8080 r6:dc68e000 r5:dda90a20
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600367] r4:de3a8080
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600430] [c1] [<c0139614>] (chrdev_open+0x0/0x178) from [<c01337d0>] (do_dentry_open+0x1a4/0x26c)
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600443] [c1]  r7:dc68e008 r6:c0139614 r5:dda90a20 r4:dc68e000
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600488] [c1] [<c013362c>] (do_dentry_open+0x0/0x26c) from [<c0133ba4>] (finish_open+0x44/0x5c)
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600501] [c1]  r9:00000000 r8:da907e98 r7:00000802 r6:da907f60 r5:00000000
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600501] r4:da907e94
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600563] [c1] [<c0133b60>] (finish_open+0x0/0x5c) from [<c0142950>] (do_last+0x3d8/0xca0)
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600576] [c1]  r5:00000000 r4:da907ee0
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600609] [c1] [<c0142578>] (do_last+0x0/0xca0) from [<c01432d8>] (path_openat+0xc0/0x4a0)
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600634] [c1] [<c0143218>] (path_openat+0x0/0x4a0) from [<c01444d0>] (do_filp_open+0x3c/0x98)
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600659] [c1] [<c0144494>] (do_filp_open+0x0/0x98) from [<c0134648>] (do_sys_open+0xf0/0x184)
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600672] [c1]  r7:00000001 r6:dc46c000 r5:ffffff9c r4:00000047
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600718] [c1] [<c0134558>] (do_sys_open+0x0/0x184) from [<c0134704>] (SyS_open+0x28/0x2c)
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600730] [c1]  r9:da906000 r8:c000e9a4 r7:00000005 r6:00000004 r5:ffffffff
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600730] r4:00000000
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600792] [c1] [<c01346dc>] (SyS_open+0x0/0x2c) from [<c000e780>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x38)
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600805] [c1] Mem-info:
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600820] [c1] Normal per-cpu:
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600835] [c1] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600850] [c1] CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:  31
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600866] [c1] CPU    2: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600880] [c1] CPU    3: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600895] [c1] CPU    4: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:  59
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600910] [c1] CPU    5: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:  30
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600925] [c1] CPU    6: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600940] [c1] CPU    7: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600952] [c1] HighMem per-cpu:
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600967] [c1] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600982] [c1] CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.600998] [c1] CPU    2: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.601013] [c1] CPU    3: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.601027] [c1] CPU    4: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.601042] [c1] CPU    5: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.601058] [c1] CPU    6: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.601073] [c1] CPU    7: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.601104] [c1] active_anon:83899 inactive_anon:4593 isolated_anon:0
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.601104]  active_file:41200 inactive_file:23749 isolated_file:0
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.601104]  unevictable:0 dirty:1757 writeback:4724 unstable:0
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.601104]  free:199161 slab_reclaimable:4434 slab_unreclaimable:104235
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.601104]  mapped:10688 shmem:5339 pagetables:703 bounce:4789
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.601104]  free_cma:91777
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.601161] [c1] Normal free:259148kB min:2756kB low:3444kB high:4132kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:128kB inactive_file:72kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:778240kB managed:474800kB mlocked:0kB dirty:16kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:17736kB slab_unreclaimable:416940kB kernel_stack:2856kB pagetables:2812kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:256516kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:296 all_unreclaimable? yes
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.601175] [c1] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 10128 10128
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.601233] [c1] HighMem free:537496kB min:512kB low:2392kB high:4272kB active_anon:335596kB inactive_anon:18372kB active_file:164672kB inactive_file:94924kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:1296384kB managed:1296384kB mlocked:0kB dirty:7012kB writeback:18896kB mapped:42752kB shmem:21356kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:876380kB free_cma:110592kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.601247] [c1] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.601280] [c1] Normal: 678*4kB (MC) 0*8kB 0*16kB 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 1*512kB (C) 0*1024kB 1*2048kB (C) 62*4096kB (C) = 259224kB
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.601387] [c1] HighMem: 3433*4kB (UM) 1557*8kB (UM) 1098*16kB (UM) 930*32kB (UM) 308*64kB (UM) 82*128kB (UM) 21*256kB (UM) 7*512kB (UM) 3*1024kB (UM) 2*2048kB (M) 102*4096kB (MRC) = 537644kB
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.601528] [c1] 70313 total pagecache pages
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.601543] [c1] 0 pages in swap cache
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.601558] [c1] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.601570] [c1] Free swap  = 0kB
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.601582] [c1] Total swap = 0kB
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616500] [c4] 518656 pages of RAM
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616515] [c4] 200048 free pages
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616522] [c4] 9021 reserved pages
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616530] [c4] 103836 slab pages
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616538] [c4] 1942637 pages shared
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616544] [c4] 0 pages swap cached
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616553] [c4] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes swapents oom_score_adj name
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616587] [c4] [  316]     0   316     1999      612       6        0             0 systemd-journal
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616599] [c4] [  325]     0   325     3027      560       6        0         -1000 systemd-udevd
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616611] [c4] [  518]   100   518     3067      270       5        0             0 systemd-timesyn
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616623] [c4] [  885]     0   885     9410      802      12        0             0 accounts-daemon
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616635] [c4] [  886]   105   886     1321      490       4        0          -900 dbus-daemon
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616645] [c4] [  892]     0   892     8669      686       8        0             0 urfkilld
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616657] [c4] [  896]   107   896     1084      381       5        0             0 avahi-daemon
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616669] [c4] [  900]   107   900     1084      136       5        0             0 avahi-daemon
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616680] [c4] [  903]   104   903     7787      464       8        0             0 rsyslogd
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616692] [c4] [  909]     0   909    10603     1716      14        0             0 ModemManager
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616703] [c4] [  914]   108   914    11270     1335      16        0             0 whoopsie
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616714] [c4] [  918]     0   918     2213     1324       7        0             0 ofonod
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616725] [c4] [  923]     0   923      866      355       3        0             0 systemd-logind
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616737] [c4] [  929]     0   929    18289     1809      18        0             0 NetworkManager
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616749] [c4] [  941]     0   941      876      246       3        0             0 cgmanager
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616760] [c4] [  950]     0   950     1324      453       4        0             0 bluetoothd
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616771] [c4] [  958]     0   958     1222      242       5        0             0 cron
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616782] [c4] [  995]     0   995     2064      595       6        0         -1000 sshd
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616793] [c4] [  999]     0   999     8325     1068      13        0             0 cups-browsed
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616805] [c4] [ 1000]     0  1000     8696      715      11        0             0 polkitd
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616816] [c4] [ 1014]     0  1014    10947      745      12        0             0 lightdm
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616827] [c4] [ 1033]     0  1033     1710      461       5        0             0 wpa_supplicant
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616838] [c4] [ 1047]     0  1047    30784     5741      36        0             0 Xorg
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616849] [c4] [ 1178]   112  1178     1635      245       6        0             0 kerneloops
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616860] [c4] [ 1181]     0  1181     3154      193       5        0             0 eGTouchD
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616872] [c4] [ 1225]     0  1225     1006      179       5        0             0 agetty
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616883] [c4] [ 1229]     0  1229      962      175       4        0             0 agetty
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616893] [c4] [ 1384]     0  1384      894      302       4        0             0 master
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616904] [c4] [ 1386]   114  1386      922      296       4        0             0 qmgr
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616915] [c4] [ 1449]     0  1449     6651      720       8        0             0 lightdm
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616926] [c4] [ 1475]  1000  1475     1602      822       5        0             0 systemd
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616936] [c4] [ 1480]  1000  1480     1748      387       6        0             0 (sd-pam)
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616947] [c4] [ 1485]  1000  1485     3448     1337       9        0             0 fluxbox
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616958] [c4] [ 1534]  1000  1534      726      243       4        0             0 unclutter
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616969] [c4] [ 1539]  1000  1539      731       83       3        0             0 ssh-agent
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616979] [c4] [ 1542]  1000  1542     1226      185       5        0             0 dbus-launch
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.616991] [c4] [ 1543]  1000  1543     1213      199       4        0             0 dbus-daemon
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.617001] [c4] [ 1559]  1000  1559     1090      309       4        0             0 d4voip.sh
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.617013] [c4] [ 1561]  1000  1561     3136     1559       8        0             0 idesk
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.617023] [c4] [ 1637]  1000  1637     1163      379       5        0             0 TopClientLogger.bsh
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.617034] [c4] [ 1638]  1000  1638     1267      243       5        0             0 logger
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.617044] [c4] [ 1703]     0  1703     3034      801       8        0             0 sshd
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.617055] [c4] [ 1883]  1000  1883     3068      409       8        0             0 sshd
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.617066] [c4] [ 1894]  1000  1894     1206      403       5        0             0 bash
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.617077] [c4] [ 2014]     0  2014     1683      400       5        0             0 sudo
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.617088] [c4] [ 2021]     0  2021     1586      353       6        0             0 su
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.617099] [c4] [ 2030]     0  2030     1243      444       5        0             0 bash
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.617111] [c4] [ 2290]  1000  2290    93900    14651      55        0             0 java
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.617122] [c4] [ 2291]  1000  2291    93009    13010      51        0             0 java
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.617133] [c4] [ 2292]  1000  2292    92993    13138      52        0             0 java
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.617145] [c4] [ 2293]     0  2293     1683      400       5        0             0 sudo
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.617158] [c4] [ 2336]     0  2336    99314    40643     110        0             0 java
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.617170] [c4] [28839]     0 28839     2867      733       7        0             0 cupsd
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.617182] [c4] [28841]     7 28841     2131      523       7        0             0 dbus
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.617193] [c4] [14795]     0 14795     3034      760       8        0             0 sshd
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.617204] [c4] [14910]  1000 14910     3067      412       7        0             0 sshd
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.617215] [c4] [14918]  1000 14918      454      182       3        0             0 sftp-server
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.617230] [c4] [24925]   114 24925      913      287       4        0             0 pickup
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.617243] [c4] [27246]     0 27246      446      190       3        0             0 anacron
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.617255] [c4] [27767]     0 27767      358      114       2        0             0 sh
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.617266] [c4] [27768]     0 27768      341      112       3        0             0 run-parts
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.617276] [c4] [27775]     0 27775      358      126       3        0             0 apt
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.617290] [c4] [28849]  1000 28849      855      122       4        0             0 sleep
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.617300] [c4] [28883]     0 28883     1865      673       6        0             0 apt-get
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.617311] [c4] [28886]     0 28886     1749      497       6        0             0 http
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.617322] [c4] [28887]     0 28887     1750      523       6        0             0 http
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.617334] [c4] [28890]     0 28890     1628      397       5        0             0 gpgv
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.617344] [c4] [28895]     0 28895     1626      447       5        0             0 copy
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.617354] [c4] Out of memory: Kill process 2336 (java) score 77 or sacrifice child
Mar 23 07:45:12 odroid kernel: [140311.623829] [c4] Killed process 2336 (java) total-vm:397256kB, anon-rss:150004kB, file-rss:12568kB
```

Is our application leaking memory? Or do we need more then 2GB of memory on the system?

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Comment: How much memory did you allocate to the JVM?

Comment: This is how we start the application:
`sudo nice -n -20 java -Xms128m -Xmx256m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing -Djava.library.path=. -jar Application.jar`
so I would say 256mb?

Comment: "-Xmx256m" You're limiting the JVM to 256 MB of heap memory. The other  754 MB of system memory is not available to it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374455/what-does-java-option-xmx-stand-for

Comment: Thank you! I will investigate why java requires more memory on this system (odroid) as opposed to our regular systems (intel).