# How can I fix my memory leak?

Tags: java, memory, ping

I made this small script to ping google.pt and do something with the ping result. The problem is that if I let the script run for a while, it uses more and more RAM.

I can't seem to find the mistake, can you help me?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String ip = "google.pt -t -4";
    int pingRetrieved = 0;

    //window that displays the ping
    s = new Square();


    String pingCmd = "ping " + ip;
    try {


        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();

        Process p = r.exec(pingCmd);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
        InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            //System.out.println(inputLine);
            pingRetrieved = getPingValueFromPingResult(inputLine);
            takeActionFromPingValue(pingRetrieved);
        }
        in.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }


}
```

EDIT: the getPingValue method:

```
private static int getPingValueFromPingResult(String inputLine) {
    String[] splitString;
    String timeParameter;
    if (inputLine.contains("Reply")) {
         splitString = inputLine.split(" ");
         timeParameter = splitString[4];
         timeParameter = (timeParameter.split("="))[1];
         timeParameter = timeParameter.replace("ms", "");
         return Integer.parseInt(timeParameter);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and the take actionFromPingValueMethod just calls this on a jframe that I created:

```
public void printNumber(int ping){

    this.getContentPane().removeAll();
    JLabel jl = new JLabel();
    Font f;
    if(ping == 0){
        this.setLocation((int) (Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth()-200), 0);
        jl = new JLabel("Connection Error");
        f = new Font("Fixedsys", Font.PLAIN, 25);
    }else{
        this.setLocation((int) (Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth()-100), 0);
        jl = new JLabel(ping+"ms");
        f = new Font("Fixedsys", Font.PLAIN, 25);
    }
    jl.setFont(f);
    jl.setForeground(Color.MAGENTA);
    this.getContentPane().add(jl, java.awt.BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.pack();

}
```

Comment: What is `takeActionFromPingValue` contains?

Comment: What do the other methods do `getPingValueFromPingResult` and `takeActionFromPingValue`.

Comment: The part of the code that your posted here has no apparent problems. It's likely in the missing methods.

Comment: I've updated with the relevant methods, sorry!

Comment: You says it use more and more RAM. Can you quantify? Have you try to set the JVM max memory ?

Comment: It is normal for a Java application to slowly accumulate more and more RAM use until the maximum allowed amount is allocated. The JVM doesn't return memory to the OS, because it does its own memory management within the memory allocated. See "garbage collection".

Comment: When I start running the script, it uses about 30 megabytes. After 2 or 3 hours of it running it uses 60-80 megabytes

Comment: @MiguelFreitas That sounds perfectly normal. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374455/what-does-java-option-xmx-stand-for.

Comment: I'll set the max memory and see what happens, I guess

Comment: @MiguelFreitas My best bet is the printNumber function. It is the only part of the code where i dont see where the variables end (Due to UI handling). Try to create the JLabel as a Static Variable and set it up once, then update the JLabel with the setText Function

Comment: @JimmyB Thanks, will do

Comment: @FlyingDutchBoy Thank you for the suggestion. I will try that.

Comment: Maybe also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667483/how-is-the-default-java-heap-size-determined.

Comment: @FlyingDutchBoy It should be a field of the class but not *static*.

Comment: @JimmyB Sorry i scoped out. The Jframe should be a static reference (should not be created for every call) and then it should have a field JLabel and a constructor that does the font, color and location stuff. That should help with a double JLabel constrution in the print function

Comment: @JimmyB Ok, I changed it. The Jframe was never being created every call, but the JLabels were. Now I put the JLabel as a class field, and I'll see if it helps. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Maybe also note that Swing may be allocating and discarding objects in the background which you are not aware of. And that `String`s are objects too, although you don't allocate them with `new`.

Answer (score 0):

the `ping` command normally runs forever and thus your condition

```
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
```

only will be false when your timeout (specified with `-t`) triggers. 
You should limit the number of ping request by using the `-c count` parameter.