# Cannot run jmeter script in bash - permission denied even though execute permissions are granted

Tags: linux, bash, jmeter, permissions

I am struggling with running jmeter.sh. I am a root user, and I have granted a required execute permission on the script file. However I keep getting error:

```
./jmeter.sh: line 111: ./jmeter: Permission denied
```

I am trying to run the script with following command:

```
./jmeter.sh -n -t mytest.jmx -l log.jtl
```

Could someone help me understand this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've granted execution permissions to [`jmeter.sh`](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.6.2/bin/jmeter.sh) wrapper script and forgot to do this for [`jmeter`](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.6.2/bin/jmeter) script

So if you give execution permissions to `jmeter` script using [chmod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) command the error will go away

```
chmod +x jmeter
```

You can also always run JMeter via `java -jar ApacheJMeter.jar` command (don't forget to set parameters like [Xmx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374455/what-does-java-option-xmx-stand-for) and [add-opens](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/migrate/index.html)

More information: [JMeter Non-GUI Mode: Useful Tips](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-non-gui-mode)